# Jenkins is not creating war file of child modules projects

Tags: maven, jenkins, parent-pom

Here is a situation, I have two projects. project `A` and `B`. I want to build this two projects together. I have repository called `Project` and Project has parent `pom.xml`. project `A` and `B` both have their respective `pom.xml`

parent `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.varun</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

  <!--<url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
  </modules>

 <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <name>M Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>my-releases</id>
        <name>My Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <!--url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url-->
    </repository>

</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

When I build using Jenkins. I do not get `A.war` and `B.war` 
What I get is `A.pom`  and `B.pom`.
Jenkins is not creating the wars
When I build both the project separately without parent pom.xml Jenkins create `A.war` and `B.war`.

How do I create the war of project `A` and `B` using parent pom.

This is the log

```
Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/A/pom.xml to com.globalss/A/1.0-SNAPSHOT/A-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/B/pom.xml to B/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/B-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Update 1 : This is my directory structure in Bit-bucket.
I have repository called project. In project I have `A` and `B` and a parent `pom.xml`.

A's `pom.xml`

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.varun</groupId>
 <artifactId>A</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.14</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
      
      </dependencies>
     </project>
```

B's `pom.xml`

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.varun</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring ORM support -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Batch -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- this jar is added to lib folder  -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
   <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </project>
```

I have remove some dependencies from the A's and B's pom to shorten the question length.

Comment: Can you post your directory structure (where are A and B located)? Can you post the POM of A and B?

Comment: Does Maven build those *.war files? Have you checked Jenkins project's workspace directory?

Comment: Yes I have checked Jenkins work-space. surprisingly i don't get target folder. When I was building A and B standalone Jenkins was building the war file. When I used the parent pom.xml, Now I don't see .war file